# Angular test - Testing a method with local variables

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I need to test this method below, but it has two variables declared inside its block.

```
loadUsers() {
    this.secService.getAllUser().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        let Data = data;
        let user = <Array<any>>Data.User;
        this.users = user.filter(f => f.idc_situacao == 'A');
      },
      error => {
        this.util.showError(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Basically the service makes a http.get request and returns the data only.

```
public getAllUser() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiSecurity.concat("/user"));
  }
```

Test:

```
describe('#loadUsers', () => {
const users = [
  {
    Company: 'Test',
    User: [
      { name: 'Link', idc_situacao: 'A' },
      { name: 'Zelda', idc_situacao: 'I' },
    ],
  },
];
    it('test', () => {
      spyOn(secService, 'getAllUser').and.returnValue(of(users));
      component.loadUsers();
      expect(component.users).toEqual([{ name: 'Link', idc_situacao: 'A' }]);
    });
  });
```

But, in the browser the test fails with the message:
Expected undefined to equal [ Object({ name: 'Link', idc_situacao: 'A' }) ]
I think it's getting undefined because the two local variables. How can I test this method?

Comment: I doubt it comes from the local variable. Can you post the full code ? (component code, and the full spec file).

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from the fact that your method is asynchronous (getAllUser).  If you add a console.log after

```
this.users = user.filter(f => f.idc_situacao == 'A')
```

you would see that the test result comes before the console.log.

You have to wait to have result of `component.loadUsers();`

```
it('test', () => {
  spyOn(secService, 'getAllUser').and.returnValue(of(users));
  const result$ = component.loadUsers();
  result$.subscribe(// write yours tests...expect()
    );
  });
});
```